# object id returned via checkbox adds extra space in the id string

Tags: javascript, database, mongoose, ejs, objectid

i was creating a to-do list where when i click the checkbox it returns the id of the item checked and then it deletes it by using findByIdAndRemove method to delete the item from my local mongoose database but the id which it returns has an extra space associated with it. i was first confused why my id was incorrect then later after some debugging i figured this problem and i have no clue why it is happening. when i trim the last character of string it fixes my problem but still why is that extra space being added?

it will be greatful to know what is causing this.

ejs code where checkbox is returning item._id

```
        <form action="/delete" method="POST">
        <div class="item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%=item._id%> " onchange="this.form.submit()">
          <p><%=  item.name  %></p>
        </div>
      </form>
      <% }) %>
```

app.js code for /delete post request route

```
app.post("/delete", function(req, res){

  let checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;
  console.log(checkedItemId + "hii");  // outputs: 60dd7cafc9bfd91808c706a6 hii
                                       // expected: 60dd7cafc9bfd91808c706a6hii

  Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId, function(err) {
    if(!err) {
      console.log("successfully deleted item");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });

  res.redirect("/");

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value="<%=item._id%> "` this space is causing the problem. Remove it, and you should be fine.